# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Database' not found

Tags: php

I try to learn oop but in my first class it gives me this error.

Database class

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Database
{
   ...
}
```

in my functions.php

```
<?php
require 'helpers.php';
require 'connection.php';
use App\Database;
...
```

Class under the "app" folder and it's namespace is "App". Why I'm getting this error ?

Comment: Can you try renaming the `app` to `App`? Make sure the namespace and directory's cases are the same.

Comment: Where is your autoloader? PHP doesn't automatically know how to map namespaced classes to the filesystem.

Comment: but we don't use autoloader other oop frameworks like symfony,laravel

Comment: You can use this one I wrote [Autoloader from GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Autoloader.php) I won't even charge you for it.  Now that I moved everything to Composer I don't need it anymore....

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thank you sir

Comment: Sure... Hope it works for you.  It's decently written.  From 2016

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, plus one for "combatable Autoloader". You may want to fix that in your file header ;)

Comment: I'm dyslexic so I cant spell.  Can't be good at everything I suppose

Comment: @Peter - looks fine now, not sure what happened. {whistle}

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, the spelling is "compatible".

Comment: @Peter - ? looks fine, maybe you need to reload it :)

Comment: I don't want to divide this nice conversation but sir how can I use this autoload class? Sorry for such a silly question @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: @cervantes - there I added full example of how it works.  It's quite flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to include the file, or use an AutoLoader. AutoLoaders tell PHP where a class can be found, as PHP needs to know the file.

Autoloaders are fully explained in the PHP documentation:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Example from the mentioned documentation:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

In this case spl_autoload_register is used to register the autoloader. The autoloader is a function which takes the class name, and includes the necessary class. For example you can use the autoloader function as used above, in which case the class name needs to be identical to the filename.
This is a quite simple example, but a more advanced autoloader could check if files exist, check multiple locations, etc...

Examples are mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705223/fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-app-database-not-found/49705281#comment86423802_49705223) on your original question.

**note:** You will find other sources mentioning the __autoload($class) function. This function does exactly the same, but [will be removed from PHP in future updates](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php). Therefore, you are better off using spl_autoload_register

Answer (score 0):

Because I posted my Autoloader in the comments.

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Autoloader.php

You can find the code at the bottom of this post:

The basic usage is as follows:

```
require_once 'Autoloader.php';

AutoLoader::getInstance()->regesterPath('\\', __DIR__);
```

This assumes it's in the directory that is the root of you namespace.  So if you have a class.

```
namespace App;

class Database{ ... }
```

And this class is in

```
 www
  |- Autoloader.php
  |- App
  | --Database.php
```

Then it will look for `__DIR__` + Namespace or `__DIR__/APP/`.  You can register paths because if you have this setup.

```
 www
  |- Autoloader.php
  |- includes
  |-- App
  | ---Database.php
```

Where the class is located in `includes/App` and Autoloader is in `/` the root folder you can do it this way.

```
require_once 'Autoloader.php';

AutoLoader::getInstance()->regesterPath('\\', __DIR__.'/includes/');
```

Also if you have it setup like this.

```
 www
  |- Autoloader.php
  |- includes
  | --Database.php
```

Where there is no actual `App` folder then you can do it like this.

```
require_once 'Autoloader.php';

AutoLoader::getInstance()->regesterPath('\\App\\', __DIR__.'/includes/');
```

Or any combination of the above.

It will account for the differences between  `\\App`. `App` and `\\App\\` for the most part.  But you can also turn on debugging with this.

```
require_once 'Autoloader.php';

$AutoLoader = AutoLoader::getInstance();
$AutoLoader->setDebug(true);
$AutoLoader>regesterPath('\\App\\', __DIR__.'/includes/');
```

And it will spit out a bunch of stuff telling you where it is looking.  You may have to use `<pre>` to keep the whitespace format, if your working in HTML.  Conveniently you can also turn off Debugging, because you may be autoloading a bunch of classes.

```
$AutoLoader->setDebug(false);
```

You can also assign multiple paths, and give them a priority and it will look in them in the order of the priority.  But that is not really important in this case.

**So for example:**

I have a folder

```
      www
       |-MISC
       |--index.php
       |--Autoloader.php
       |---IMAP
       |----GmailClient.php
```

Which is also in the same Git Repo.  It has the namespace of `Lib\Email\IMAP` of which only the `IMAP` exists.

And to load It if I do this in index.php, which is inside the `MISC` file and at the same level as the `AutoLoader.php` file:

```
 //include the Autoloader
 require_once __DIR__.'/Autoloader.php';

 //get an instance of it (Singleton pattern)
 $Autoloader = Autoloader::getInstance();

 //regester a namespace, path pair
 $Autoloader->regesterPath('Lib\Email', __DIR__.'/IMAP/');

 //preserve whitespace
 echo "<pre>";

 //turn on debugging before a problem class
 $Autoloader->setDebug(true);

 //Attempt to load the class as normal
 $G = new GmailClient($hostname, $username, $password);

 //turn off debugging after trying to load a problem class.
 $AutoLoader->setDebug(false);
```

This is what it Outputs for debugging

```
================================= Autoloader::debugMode ==================================
Autoloader::splAutoload Lib\Email\IMAP\GmailClient
Checking class: GmailClient
Checking namespace: Lib/Email/IMAP
checking pathname:C:/Server/www/MISC/IMAP/IMAP/GmailClient.php
==========================================================================================
```

Right away we can see `C:/Server/www/MISC/IMAP/IMAP/GmailClient.php` That IMAP is in there 2x.  This is because I included that in the path,  So it starts looking in `C:/Server/www/MISC/IMAP/` and then adds the namespace that wasn't given in the namespace arg  `IMAP` from `Lib/Email/IMAP`. We gave it `Lib/Email` as the first argument. So essentially, because this was part of the path it's already in that folder when it looks for that.

So If I just remove that `IMAP` from the path:

```
$Autoloader->regesterPath('Lib\Email', __DIR__);
```

It will output this:

```
================================= Autoloader::debugMode ==================================
Autoloader::splAutoload Lib\Email\IMAP\GmailClient
Checking class: GmailClient
Checking namespace: Lib/Email/IMAP
checking pathname:C:/Server/www/MISC/IMAP/GmailClient.php
Found: C:/Server/www/MISC/IMAP/GmailClient.php
==========================================================================================
```

With the most important line being this

```
Found: C:/Server/www/MISC/IMAP/GmailClient.php
```

Which obviously means that it found the class file and loaded it.

Hope that makes sense.

Following is the full code for the autoloader, that way the answer wont break if anything changes with the Repo I linked.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * (c) 2016 ArtisticPhoenix
 *
 * For license information please view the LICENSE file included with this source code. GPL-3
 *
 * PSR4 compatible Autoloader
 * 
 * @author ArtisticPhoenix
 * @see http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
 * 
 * @example
 * $Autoloader = Autoloader::getInstance();
 * //looks in includes for folder named /includes/Lib/Auth/User/
 * $Autoloader->regesterPath('Lib\\Auth\\User', __DIR__.'/includes/');
 *
 */
final class Autoloader
{
    /**
     *
     * @var int
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRIORITY = 10;

    /**
     * namespace / class path storage
     * @var array
     */
    private $paths = array();

    /**
     * cashe the loaded files
     * @var array
     */
    private $files = array();

    /**
     * namespace / class path storage
     * @var array
     */
    private $debugMode = false;

    /**
     *
     * @var Self
     */
    private static $instance;


    /**
     * No public construction allowed - Singleton
     */
    private function __construct($throw, $prepend)
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array( $this,'splAutoload'), $throw, $prepend);
    }

    /**
     * No cloning of allowed
     */
    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    /**
     *
     * Get an instance of the Autoloader Singleton
     * @param boolean $throw
     * @param boolean $prepend
     * @return self
     */
    public static function getInstance($throw = false, $prepend = false)
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self($throw, $prepend);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * set debug output
     * @param boolean $debug
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDebug($debug = false)
    {
        $this->debugMode = $debug;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Autoload
     * @param string $class
     */
    public function splAutoload($class)
    {
        $this->debugMode('_START_');
        $this->debugMode(__METHOD__.' '.$class);
        //keep the orignal class name
        $_class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
        $namespace = '';
        if (false !== ($pos = strrpos($_class, '/'))) {
            $namespace = substr($_class, 0, ($pos));
            $_class = substr($_class, ($pos + 1));
        }
        //replace _ in class name only
        if (false !== ($pos = strrpos($_class, '/'))) {
            if (strlen($namespace)) {
                $namespace .= '/'.substr($_class, 0, ($pos));
            } else {
                $namespace = substr($_class, 0, ($pos));
            }
            $_class = substr($_class, ($pos + 1));
        }

        $this->debugMode("Checking class: $_class");
        $this->debugMode("Checking namespace: $namespace");
        do {
            if (isset($this->paths[ $namespace ])) {
                foreach ($this->paths[ $namespace ] as $registered) {
                    $filepath = $registered['path'] . $_class . '.php';

                    $this->debugMode("checking pathname:{$filepath}");
                    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
                        $this->debugMode("Found: $filepath");
                        $this->debugMode('_END_');
                        require_once $filepath;
                        $this->files[$class] = $filepath;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (strlen($namespace) == 0) {
                //if the namespace is empty and we couldn't find the class we are done.
                break;
            }

            if (false !== ($pos = strrpos($namespace, '/'))) {
                $_class = substr($namespace, ($pos + 1)) . '/' . $_class;
                $namespace = substr($namespace, 0, ($pos));
            } else {
                $_class = (strlen($namespace) ? $namespace : '') . '/' . $_class;
                $namespace = '';
            }
        } while (true);
        $this->debugMode('_END_');
    }

    /**
     * get the paths regestered for a namespace, leave null go get all paths
     * @param string $namespace
     * @return array or false on falure
     */
    public function getRegisteredPaths($namespace = null)
    {
        if (is_null($namespace)) {
            return $this->paths;
        } else {
            return (isset($this->paths[$namespace])) ? array($namespace => $this->paths[$namespace])  : false;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param string $namespace
     * @param string $path
     * @param int $priority
     * @return self
     */
    public function regesterPath($namespace, $path, $priority = self::DEFAULT_PRIORITY)
    {
        $namespace = str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace); //convert to directory seperator
        $path = ($this->normalizePath($path));

        $this->paths[$namespace][sha1($path)] = array(
            'path'        => $path,
            'priority'    => $priority
        );
        $this->sortByPriority($namespace);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * un-regester a path
     * @param string $namespace
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function unloadPath($namespace, $path = null)
    {
        if ($path) {
            $path = $this->normalizePath($path);
            unset($this->paths[$namespace][sha1($path)]);
        } else {
            unset($this->paths[$namespace]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * check if a namespace is regestered
     * @param string $namespace
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isRegistered($namespace, $path = null)
    {
        if ($path) {
            $path = $this->normalizePath($path);
            return isset($this->paths[$namespace][sha1($path)]) ? true : false;
        } else {
            return isset($this->paths[$namespace]) ? true : false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * get the file pathname of a loaded class
     * @param string $class
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLoadedFile($class = null)
    {
        if (!$class) {
            return $this->files;
        }

        if (isset($this->files[$class])) {
            return $this->files[$class];
        }
    }
    /**
     * output debug message
     * @param string $message
     */
    protected function debugMode($message)
    {
        if (!$this->debugMode) {
            return;
        }

        switch ($message) {
            case '_START_':
                echo str_pad("= ".__METHOD__." =", 90, "=", STR_PAD_BOTH) . PHP_EOL;
            break;
            case '_END_':
                echo str_pad("", 90, "=", STR_PAD_BOTH) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
            break;
            default:
                echo $message . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * sort namespaces by priority
     * @param string $namespace
     */
    protected function sortByPriority($namespace)
    {
        uasort($this->paths[$namespace], function ($a, $b) {
            return ($a['priority'] > $b['priority']) ? true : false;
        });
    }

    /**
     * convert a path to unix seperators and make sure it has a trailing slash
     * @param string $path
     * @return string
     */
    protected function normalizePath($path)
    {
        if (false !== strpos($path, '\\')) {
            $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path);
        }

        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/';
    }
}
```

P.S. the GmailClient class I used in this example, I wrote to parse incoming Emails in a Gmail account.  It's not 100% fleshed out as we needed it for a specific purpose.  But it is in the same GitHub repository.

Comment: Why not `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `"/"`, just in case.

Comment: Lazyness.... the `/` is one key, the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is a bunch and it always worked for me on both linux and windows.  Also I haven't used this class in about a year as I moved everything to Composer which comes with an Autoloader.  If they had used `__DS__` I would use it all the time.

Comment: Maybe I will change it an use a class constant set to = `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR `  I just can't bring my self to type that out.